# How to combine many XSL files into one?

Tags: java, xslt, flatten

I have XSL files organized as tree structures with using inheritance with `xsl:import` directive. It's very convenient for development. But for backward compatibility, I need to produce a flat XSL file, packed in a **JAR artefact**.
Does someone know a tool or library that can do flattening of XSL files (preferably in Java)?

Comment: Why do you think you need to flatten the xsl from multiple files to a single file? Why not pack multiple xsl's into the jar and reference via xsl:import?

Comment: It is of course possible to load a stylesheet and its imported modules all from a jar file. On the other hand, if you want a single file and don't want to role something on your own but perhaps live in the modern world of XSLT 3 with Saxon and have (perhaps as on oXygen user) access to Saxon EE, it can create/export a single SEF for your stylesheet, with different targets (e.g. Saxon HE or PE or EE, SaxonJS) so that you then, in your JAR, you would only need to include the SEF.

Comment: @Sumit Singh "directive" is not code, and "artefact" is not a word. Find better use of your time.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's not possible to flatten an XSLT stylesheet in this way. That's because a template rule in one module has higher precedence than a template rule in a module that it imports; if you want to move the two template rules into a single module then you need to assign explicit priorities to achieve the same effect; and even then it can't be reproduced exactly in all cases.

Of course there might be cases where it IS possible, if you don't use overrides in this way.